# Spring Roo : difference between [controller scaffold --class] and [web mvc scaffold --class ]

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-roo

Spring Roo : difference between [controller scaffold --class] and [web mvc scaffold --class ]

Now we will want to scaffold a web tier for conference application. This is done using the controller command. The most convenient way to generate controllers and all relevant web artifacts is to use controller all.

bUT WHAT DIFFERENCE?

thnks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `controller scaffold` is equivalent to `web mvc scaffold`.  However `controller scaffold` is deprecated.  look in A.4.2 [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-web-mvc-scaffold)